# Truncate rows and insert new ones without introducing a service break?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have about 1,500,000 records in a PostgreSQL 9.5 database table, and I'm getting a CSV file (through an http post request) that contains new ~1,500,000 rows, where some are unchanged, some are different, and some are removed compared to the original rows.

I then

1. Truncate the old table
2. Loop through the CSV file's rows
3. Insert each row into the table

What I need is a way to do this *without* introducing a service break to my customers, i.e. the service should keep using the old data until all three steps are done. Currently the service break would be ~1 hour long, that's how long it takes to read the CSV and insert all new lines. I'm fine with a 5 min break if that's required.

How can I achieve such behavior?

Here's a shortened version of my Python script:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=DictCursor)
cursor.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE rows CASCADE')
with open(request.files.csv) as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        row = parse_line(line)
        cursor.execute(
            '''INSERT INTO rows (name, bla, blu)
            VALUES (%(name)s, %(bla)s, %(blu)s)''',
            row,
        )
cursor.commit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. use `COPY` instead of `with open(request.files.csv)`, because 1,500,000 rows are copied from CSV to a table in seconds
2. if those seconds (let assume one minute) is too long, just using transaction won't help, cause [truncate requires lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html) on table, not rows

> TRUNCATE acquires an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock on each table it operates
>   on

So if you can rebuild all dependant objects on the table, hte best probably would be:

```
create t_table as select * from "rows" where false;
copy t_table from request.files.csv;
--build all needed dependant objects (indexes, constraints,triggers);
begin;
  alter table "rows" rename to "some_name";
  alter table "t_table " rename to "rows";
end;
--here is a miliseconds glitch to swith for users (if you use memcache or so - need to refresh it)
drop table "some_name";
```

**update**
[to copy columns from csv to several table columns list columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

> COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]

Comment: Truncate will affect other transactions that are working with snapshot before truncate command was issues, so it wouldn't fit `the service should keep using the old data until all three steps are done` requirement anyway.

Comment: This seems awesome, thanks! Just one follow up question; the CSV file has ~20 columns, but my table only needs five of them. Can I copy only five particular columns somehow, or should I edit the CSV with Python before forwarding it to the database?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen updated. use `copy t_table(col1,col4,col5,etc) from request.files.csv;`

Comment: @VaoTsun Thanks, this is all some highly advanced stuff for me (as in I've never heard of before), gotta do some more research and learn all this well. You're awesome, accepted :)

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I suggest solution without truncate at all - just drop old table. users will read original table until the very swith with filled in new table

Comment: Okay one more question if you don't mind, what does the very first line do? Why the `where false;`?

Comment: first line clones structure of original table. where false to omit data - only column names and datatypes to copy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143472/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-markus-meskanen).